# Impact of upgrading Sharpoint 2013 to Sharpoint 2013 Service Pack 1 on SSRS Reports

Tags: upgrade, reporting-services

Hope you all are doing well!

We have a BI System that consists of SQL server Reporting Services 2008 R2 and we have deployed the reports on Sharepoint 2013. We were planning to upgrade the Sharepoint 2013 with the Sharepoint 2013 SP1 version and wanted to check if this upgrade might have any impact on the SSRS reports deployed to Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any impact /side effect on SSRS while Updating the SharePoint farm to SP1. But the only way you can see any potential issue you have to apply the CU in lower farm(test/dev) first, then test it.

I would recommend move the production data in dev farm and then apply the CU and do the testing. This will give you maximum comfort.